# encoding on my server

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

hi i made website with arabic content on my localhost by asp.net using utf8 encoding and embed flash slideshow 
but when i published it on the server the arabic letters became like this:
 Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù†Ø­Ù€Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø§Ù…Ù„Ù€Ø©

```
Ù…Ø¯ØªÙ‡Ø§ :- Ø´Ù‡Ø±ÙŠÙ†
Ø¹Ø¯Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§ÙŠØ§Ù… :- 5 Ø£ÙŠØ§Ù… Ø£Ø³Ø¨ÙˆØ¹ÙŠØ§
Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¹Ø± :- (950 ) Ø¬Ù†ÙŠÙ‡
Ø¹Ø¯Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø³ÙŠÙ† :- 500 Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø³ ØµØ¨Ø§Ø­Ø§ ÙˆÙ…Ø³Ø§Ø¡
```

Ø§Ù„Ø´Ù‡Ø§Ø¯Ø§Øª Ù„ÙƒÙ„

can any one help me please??? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Probably the server did not have the same settings as you, so change the web.config and add that line

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

More information's on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thank you for your response but the problem is still the site was running perfect and when i browse today i found it like this

Comment: @HassanMustafa Do you add this line on your web.config ?